# Cheaper in-app purchases

Tags: google-play-store, localization

I play Game of War Fire Age and wondering if I can get cheaper packs on it, I'm from the UK and it costs me £79.99 to buy a pack but my Brazilian friend only pays $60 for the same pack, is there anyway for me to be able to change my region to Brazil and get the same deal, but then the only problem is my billing address, let me know if there is a way.

Answer (score 6):

> is there anyway for me to be able to change my region to Brazil

Yes. But it may not be that easy.

I've done it twice, and each time was hit-and-miss. The first time, it only changed once I made a purchase with my new billing details. The second time it didn't work and I ended up deleting all my payment details, wiping my phone, and setting up the phone and payments, with a SIM card from my target country.

Also note that if you change your country to Brazil, the play store will show up in Portuguese and you will only be able to see/buy services (such as Newsstand, Video, Music, etc) that are available in Brazil (which may be less than what the UK has).

Google changes the country your billing is associated with according to your Google Play billing method. These are the instructions I followed from Google -

> We use the billing address of your default payment instrument in Google Wallet >to help determine your home country for accessing the Play Store. Our collection of content can vary by country, so your view of the Play Store may differ from what others are seeing when you travel outside of the country listed on your default payment method's billing address.
>
> Please note that you must have a valid payment method with a billing address located inside a country in order to access that country's Play Store.
>
> If you're having issues viewing your intended country's Play Store and would like to change your default payment method or update an existing billing address in Google Wallet, please use the following steps:
>
> 1) Sign into your Google Wallet account to manage your payment methods https://wallet.google.com/manage/paymentMethods
>
> 2) Add a new card or change your default payment instrument to one with a billing address located inside your desired country
>
> 3) Open the Play Store and navigate to any item available for download
>
> 4) Click to begin a download until you reach the "Accept and buy" screen (no need to complete the purchase)
>
> 5) Close the Play Store and clear data for the Google Play Store application (Settings > Apps > Google Play Store > Clear Data) or clear your browser cache
>
> 6) Re-open the Play Store. You should now see the Play Store that matches your default payment instrument's billing country.
>
> If you haven't yet added a payment method to your account for the first time, please add a card directly from the Play Store with a billing address that matches your intended country location. Then, follow steps 3 through 6 to show your intended country's Play Store.
>
> If you believe that you're experiencing a different location-related issue, please first verify if the country of your primary payment method matches your intended country. If the countries match, please provide any screenshots and additional details that might help me resolve your issue.

Comment: I have tried this twice and have not gotten it to work for me.

Comment: @user166930 Whitebear did state it was "hit-and-miss".

Answer (score 1):

You can get Google Play Store credits from Google by answering polls through the [*Google Opinion Rewards* app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.paidtasks). Depending on where in the world you are, you can get a couple of dollars every month by spending 5–15 minutes answering a few questions.

The credits you earn can be used towards in-app purchases and other purchases through the Google Play Store. This way, you would indeed get cheaper in-app purchases but you’d have to work a little to get it.